# Can't seem to pass return of React custom hook directly to React context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

The pattern I often follow when building React apps is to create a custom React hook that returns state data to me, then assign those state values to a React context so I can have access to them in my component hierarchy.  The code usually looks like this:

```
  const { notesData, notesDataError } =
    useNotes();
  const contextValue = { notesData, notesDataError };

  return (
      <NotesContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        <NoteList />
      </NotesContext.Provider>
  );
```

I was thinking I can shorten but just passing what is returned from useNotes() and assign that to the contextValue without having to explicitly name every property

When I try that (see code below), it seems the values don't pass.  I expect that the top code will behave the same as the bottom code, but instead, my value for notesData is undefined which I assume means because the properties did not go through.

```
  const contextValue = useNotes();

  return (
      <NotesContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        <NoteList />
      </NotesContext.Provider>
  );
```

Could someone tell me how to get those values to go through without having to mention every one of them?

Comment: You're right, it should work. Error must be somewhere else, can you create a Codepen with a complete example?

Comment: What does `useNotes` do? What is the first returned value from `useNotes`? The reason why the first one works is because you are creating a new object and pass it to context. So, if anything else updates the component, the context will be changed. However, if `useNotes` memoizes data or just returns value of `useState`, which never changes its reference, the context will not be even if the component is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example actually does work. I am the poster of the question and I was not initializing the state data correctly in the custom hook.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why what you're trying to do doesn't work, but here's a workaround that should get you what you want:

(Creating a new object with the spread operator)

```
  const contextValue = useNotes();

  return (
      <NotesContext.Provider value={{...contextValue}}>
        <NoteList />
      </NotesContext.Provider>
  );
```

And I'm not sure about the efficiency of this workaround, but it should be the same (if not faster) than manually destructuring each key and making a new object

Comment: hmm. just tried that and it didn't work.  I'll need to work on a codeplen. It will take me a while to get that together.